Importing a yaml file in Nuxt3
The yaml file in question looks like this:
timepoints_number: |
  The number of timepoints to be used in the experiment. This will be used to generate the final identifiers.
timepoints_unit: |
    The unit to use for the timepoints. This will not be used to generate the final identifiers.

...with plenty of lines like the above.
It's imported into a .vue file in the application like this:
import definitions from "@/assets/data/definitions.yml"


export default {
  name: "CreatorConditions",
  data() { return { definitions: { ...definitions } } },
  ...

My nuxt.config.js file contains:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  plugins: ["@modyfi/vite-plugin-yaml"]

...yet attempts to run npm run build result in:
[13:43:27]  ERROR  Nuxt Build Error: src/assets/data/definitions.yml (1:19): Expression expected (Note that you need plugins to imp
ort files that are not JavaScript)
file: ./src/assets/data/definitions.yml:1:19

1: timepoints_number: |
                      ^
2:   The number of timepoints to be used in the experiment. This will be used to generate the final identifiers.
3: timepoints_unit: |


  file: src/assets/data/definitions.yml:1:19

N.B. there were no such issues using Nuxt2 and Webpack.
Can anyone suggest how to fix this?
